# touchesMoved seen by all view controllers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesmoved

I have a ViewController that defines touchesMoved() to increment a counter as a user drags a finger over the screen:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    numMoved += 1
    print("Moved: \(numMoved)")
}
```

When the user goes to another view controller which doesn't have touchesMoved() defined, I expect that nothing would happen. (The new view controller is defined to be of class OtherViewController, which inherits directly from UIViewController and so does not get the touchesMoved() override I had defined for the first view controller.)

However, after tapping a button that brings me to the other view controller, I still see the printed messages, meaning touchesMoved() is still being invoked even though I am no longer on the original view controller that is tracking the drag.

Am I missing some simple thing that would ensure that the override to touchesMoved() only affects the ViewController it is defined within?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: What does "goes to another view controller" mean? Goes _how_? I'm trying to get you to state the relationship between ViewController and OtherViewController.

Comment: The main view controller is the default ViewController while the OtherViewController is something I've created as a subclass of UIViewController.  I've placed a button on ViewController that segues to OtherViewController modally.  There are no other relationships between the two view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining `touchesMoved` in a view controller, define it in a *view*. The main view of the view controller will do. (You will need to subclass UIView and make the main view of the view controller an instance of this subclass.)

It will have the same effect, but now you are not in the view controller hierarchy and you won't get messages from the other view controller's views.

Another alternative: pull a UITouch out of the `touches:` and look at its `view`. If this isn't your view, ignore this call.

Comment: Defining it in a view rather than a view controller does fix the problem so I've accepted the answer (thanks!) but I'm still not sure why a completely independent view controller would conflict with the move events of another view controller.

Comment: It is not "completely independent". That is why I asked you to tell me the relationship between the two view controllers. They have a relationship! ViewController is the presenting view controller. OtherViewController is the presented view controller. That means that ViewController is next up the _responder chain_ from OtherViewController. So when OtherViewController fails to handle `touchesMoved`, it is walked further up the responder chain and reaches ViewController.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your explanation: when a view controller , A, segues to another view controller, B, via a modal segue, then A is part of the responder chain to events in B?  If that's the case, then I guess B should not modally segue back to A when it is done since that would create a longer responder chain rather than shorten it back to one without B.  Is that correct?  Thanks.

Comment: The opposite of present is dismiss, not another present. That is obvious. But it has nothing to do with what I said.